# How do I iterate through a data frame to print all possible combinations of two list columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a datavframe:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A, B |
| 3 | A, B, C |

I want to print every possible combination from the two lists on a new row.
The output should look something like:

```
1A
2A 
2B
3A 
3B 
3C
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `split` `Column2` into list then `explode` `Column2`. At last join two columns and convert to list.

```py
out = (df.assign(Column2=df['Column2'].str.split(', '))
       .explode('Column2')
       # [['Column1', 'Column2']] # uncomment this line if there are more than two target columns
       .astype(str)
       .agg(''.join, axis=1)
       .tolist())
```

```
print(out)

['1A', '2A', '2B', '3A', '3B', '3C']
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use pure python here:

```
from itertools import product
out = [''.join(x) for a,b in zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2'])
       for x in product([str(a)], b.split(', '))]
```

output: `['1A', '2A', '2B', '3A', '3B', '3C']`

Classical loop:

```
for a,b in zip(df['Column1'], df['Column2']):
    for x in product([str(a)], b.split(', ')):
        print(''.join(x))
```

output:

```
1A
2A
2B
3A
3B
3C
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. However, if there is an empty value in Column 2, it does not create a combination after the first element. In my particular case, there is no Column 2 value for row 4 or row 5. So it only displays a 3A but not 3B and 3C.

Comment: What do you mean by row 4/5? There are only 3 rows in the provided input. You can always `fillna('')` the columns to ensure having a working product (this would give `1` if `A` is missing in row 0)

Comment: Sorry @mozway your solution does work. I accidentally forgot to add a space between one the list elements!

Comment: @Missm great! If the space is optional you can use `re.split(r',\s*', )` instead of `b.split(', ')`. (`import re` in the preamble)

Comment: Is there a way to add additional columns?

Comment: Yes, add them in the `zip` as well as extra variables

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [str(x.Column1) + item for item in x.Column2.split(', ')], axis=1).explode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
import re
out = df.apply(lambda x: list(
                product([str(x['Column1'])], list(re.sub('\s*,\s*', '', x['Column2'])))),
               axis=1)
out = [''.join(b) for a in out for b in a]
```

print(out):

```
['1A', '2A', '2B', '3A', '3B', '3C']
```